# How to send an email in response to a triggered event?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, event

We need to send emails in response to a triggered event. We have created two data extension, one for client data and another to event data. These data extensions are filled with API procedures.

We have a query to join this information in a data extension to send in the email.
We don´t know how we can create a campaign (or other element in ExactTarget application), to wait the event and immediately send the email in response to this event.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting use case. Can you give us some more details around what code you have specifically tried that isn't working, or something that we can narrow down the responses with?  This is a fairly broad topic otherwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding the request correctly, you have the data in a series of data extensions that will be used to personalize the message but you're just looking to trigger the message.

Assuming a need for a near real time message, I would look into one of the following messages:

1. [Transactional Rest API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm) - Good for firing transactional messages very quickly but requires the use of a transactional send classification. There is a Trailhead Live on this topic available [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/live/videos/a2r3k000001n2I7/build-transactional-journeys-with-the-marketing-cloud-rest-api/). While this is a developer focused session, the concepts are introduced and covered in detail prior to API portion. Alternatively, there is also a new journey type "Transactional" to handle all pieces of the message definition setup.
2. [Triggered Sends](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_triggered_sends.htm&type=5) - Good for firing messages in real time (can be a commercial or transactional send classification).

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the kind of event:

If it is an event that is included in the Measures function then:

- Use a data filter based on the given measure (open email, click...)
- Include the data filter as an activity in a workflow automation in Automation studio.
- Include an Send activity in the workflow to the outcome of the data filter.
- Set the Automation to run daily.

Follow the link for information on measures function. http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/measures/

If it is not an event included in Measures function then

- Create a data filter using the data in the data extension where you keep the event information.
- Include the data filter as an activity in a workflow automation in Automation studio.
- Include an Send activity in the workflow automation to the outcome of the data filter.
- Set the Automation to run daily.

In both cases the emails that will be sent will not be after the event has happened. All emails will be sent when the Automation runs.

Comment: You may also want to consider the option of using journey builder, and consider using the source DE as your resultant DE(which is formed using the query activity. In your journey you can schedule the automation(fire event ) to run hourly, Please let me know if you have additional questions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you've already solved for the audience and the content, right?  You have an email ready to go and you know who to send it to, but you only want to send it after some external event has occurred?

What about using the File Drop trigger in Automation Studio? If your external process can drop a file onto your FTP server, the automation can be set to watch for that file and then act as soon as it receives it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a landing page/microsite to receive a phone number or email address parameter and then send a triggered email or sms.

Answer (score 0):

I see two options here:

1. If the eventdata dataextension has the subscriberkey/emailaddress, you could use the eventdata dataextension as the dataextension for an API triggered journey.
   When the event happens, the eventdata DE gets populated by your APIcall, and sends the subscriber through the journey. You can query any clientdata you need to render the email using ampscript in the email body.
2. If you really need this query before you run the emailsend, I would put this query in an Automation. This Automation (#1) will have three activities;  the query activity, the activity that fires the journey, and a script activity. The script activity calls a second automation (#2). This second automation will have a script activity that calls Automation #1 again.
   This way you can reduce the automation schedule from one hour to 5 or 10 minutes.
   The email will be sent directly after the event, with a  minimal delay of 5 to 10 minutes.